# How do I Display results from Oracle query to the console

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get `20` records from all tables on my schema but my code doesn't work.

```
BEGIN
    FOR R IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'dbms_output.put_line(select * from '||r.table_name||' where rownum<=20)';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Someone know why or can help me with this case?

Comment: The result of a select is not a string (`varchar`), so it cannot be used with `put_line`. The whole logic is off...

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Im using 11G version

Comment: This would be possible in 12.x but I don't think there is an easy solution for the outdated 11.x

Answer (score 2):

> " i need to export 20 records from all tables on my schema. I had a plan to do it in sqlplus and save the output with spool option"

You can do this but it's a two step process:

1. Generate the SELECT statements and spool them to a `.sql` file
2. Run the generated script

So something like this in SQL*Plus :

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> spool get20rows.sql
SQL> select 'prompt '||table_name from user_tables;
SQL> select 'select * from '||table_name||' where rownum <= 20;'
SQL> from user_tables;
SQL> spool off
SQL> 
SQL> spool get20rows.out
SQL> @get20rows.sql
SQL> spool off
```

Improving the spooled layout is left as an exercise for the reader :) As @Williamrobertson observes...

> The results from a plain `select * from sometable` will typically be unreadable due to wrapping

Comment: `select 'prompt '||table_name|| from user_tables;` you have a second string concatenation operator but no following string.

Comment: @kaushik - that one I'm definitely blaming the app for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To output the SQL query you do not need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and can just call `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` directly:

```
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'select * from "'||r.table_name||'" where rownum<=20;' );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then you can run the outputted statements to get your desired results.

Also, identifiers are, by default, created with upper-case names; however, if a user creates a table/column/etc using double-quotes then the case-sensitivity of the identifier will be maintained and you will need double quotes in your query.

Comment: Yes it works but i need to export 20 records from all tables on my schema. I had a plan to do it in sqlplus and save the output with spool option. Is it possible or  i have to do queries one by one?

Comment: What format do you need this in? The results from a plain `select * from sometable` will typically be unreadable due to wrapping (try it). Do you need a generic CSV generator? There are tools to do this.

Comment: Another option is SQLcl ( java based sqlplus which is core of sqldev ) see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894107/3715100